# Erase pdfAnnotation added using pdfkit

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, pdf-annotations, pdfpage

I used the below code to draw a line to a pdfpage. Is there any way i can erase the annotation like an eraser when user drags over it.

```
let lineAttributes: [PDFAnnotationKey: Any] = [ .linePoints: [startPoint.x, startPoint.y, point.x, point.y],
            .lineEndingStyles: [PDFAnnotationLineEndingStyle.none,PDFAnnotationLineEndingStyle.none], .color: UIColor.red,.border: PDFBorder() ]
            let lineAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: pageBounds , forType: .line,withProperties: lineAttributes)
            lineAnnotation.border = border
            lineAnnotation.color = selectedcolor
            page!.addAnnotation(lineAnnotation)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) add pan gesture recognizer to your PDFView

2) keep track of the gesture and in the right moment (like the gesture goes over the annotation) call `page.removeAnnotation(lineAnnotation)`

this is how you can get the touch location inside the page from the gesture recognizer

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationInView:self.pdfView];
PDFPage * pdfPage = [self.pdfView pageForPoint:touchLocation nearest:NO];
if (pdfPage == nil) {
    return;
}

CGPoint pageLocation = [self.pdfView convertPoint:touchLocation toPage:pdfPage];
```